# Is there a way to disable the 'review' step when creating a post on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, edits, ask-question-form

I noticed something changed on Stack Overflow a while back. At first it didn't bother me, but lately it's really starting to annoy me.

Whenever I write a post, even if I'm using the live 'preview' feature as I'm writing, I can't simply submit it. I have to first preview it, *again*, then click publish.

As I said, and most people know, that's new functionality, but I don't really see the point if I'm already looking at a preview as I type. It seems redundant, which tweaks every [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obsessive%E2%80%93compulsive_disorder) tendency of programmers!

So... can that feature be disabled to just go back to an actual post, eliminating that step?

or...

Can someone explain why that step is needed, that I'm just not seeing and it won't bother me when it's shown to me?

Comment: it's needed for the system to review your question to find if there is some improvement to be done before your submit it. It's not related to the *preview*. If you write a good question then you will pass the review in most of the cases.

Comment: But are you sure?  It *always* comes up for me, and I simply press 'Publish' and it goes through.  And if you look at my questions, they are pretty thorough and clear.

Comment: Plus, it even says 'review' not 'publish' on the button.  If it was something they wanted to check first, they could intercept the publish, check it, and if it's all good just let it go.  There's no need for a manual two-step process.

Comment: it comes up for everyone and the review is always good for you before you publish .. maybe one day you will fail

Comment: But it is *always* failing if it's always getting in the way!  Plus, as I said, I have *already* reviewed it with the preview being there as I'm editing.

Comment: as I said, it has nothing to do with *your* review or the *preview*. There is a system review step that need to be done to your post before you publish and in your case you always pass that step with a *good* review. Maybe one day you will get a notification about something you need to change

Comment: But *again*, nothing is stopping the system from performing the review automatically before publishing, and if it's good, just publish it.  You still haven't explained why if it's a *system* review, why *I* have to review it.  That is my point.

Comment: In other words, if the system reviews it and it's good, just publish it. If there's an issue, ***then*** show me the extra step where it's saying more action is needed.   But don't *always* make me have to take that step.

Comment: it was designed to work that way, you need to click a button so your question get reviewed when you are done then you publish if it's ok

Comment: I just feel it's needless extra clicks.  The same thing could be achieved with a 'Review and publish' button.  If it passes, it just publishes. If it fails, it goes to review. Not sure what else to add here.

Comment: There's currently a bug- if you hit enter while adding tags it will skip review. No guarantees that it'll stick around. Also not sure what happens if you fail a requirement.